# How can i convert java java.nio.ByteBuffer to spring org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile?

Tags: java, spring

How can i convert an object of type java.nio.ByteBuffer to spring MultipartFile object .

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ByteBuffer** provides an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array()) method (with signature `public final byte[] array()`) which can be used to return a `byte[]`.

This can be provided as an input to the constructor of [MockMultipartFile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartFile.html#MockMultipartFile-java.lang.String-byte:A-) (with signature `public MockMultipartFile(String name, @Nullable byte[] content)`), which implements **MultipartFile**, as below and create a `MultipartFile` object

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1); //any kind of ByteBuffer initialization that you have
byte[] byteArray = buffer.array();

MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("fileName", byteArray);
```